# RxJava2: Iterate over items and get the item matching a condition

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java2

I have an in my opinion trivial task which seems to have non-trivial solution with RX.

**Scenario:**

I have a list of number generators which shall be aggregated by a specific module using a complex algorithm, which is unknown to me. I can feed the algorithm with the output of the number generator. Afterwards, I can request an aggregated number from the algorithm.

I want to iterator over all of my number generators until the algorithm returns a number matching my condition.

**Current approach:**

```
return generators.getGenerators().flatMapObservable {
            Observable
                    .fromIterable(it)
                    .flatMap { generator: NumberGenerator ->
                        generator.getNumber()
                                .flatMapCompletable { data: NumberData ->
                                    algorithm.inject(data)
                                }
                                .andThen(algorithm.getAggregatedNumber()) 
                    }
                    .skipWhile {
                        it.value == 0.0f || it.value < minLevel
                    }
                    .firstOrError()
                    .toObservable()
        }
```

Some explainations:

`algorithm` is a member of my class. It has the two functions used by the code above. `inject` directly modifies the result returned by `getAggregatedNumber`.

`generators.getGenerators()` returns a Single>. This is a requirement of the interface of the Generators class, so it can't be changed to Observable. This is why I have to map it to an observable inside the `flatMapObservable`.

Everytime I inject a number from a generator into the algorithm I must check if the aggregated number matches a given condition (i.e. reaches the `minLevel`). If so, I want to return that single value and unsubscribe from remaining generators.

With other words: when the condition is met, the remaining generators should not be "executed", i.e. no getNumber() and no algorithm.inject should happen after that.

**some assumptions**

`takeWhile` emits items until the condition is met and complets. Unfortunatelly, this will skip the actual item I am interested in.

`skipWhile` skips all uninteresting items and start emitting those I want. However, I only want the very first item matching the condition, the rest of the stream is not interesting and thus should not be emitted nor executed.

`filter` iterates over everything emitting only the items of interest. However, this works the same as `skipUntil` because of the interna of the algorithm.

simple `for`-loops: well, most of the code is using Observables etc., so I thought it is a breach when I interrupt the stream using for-loops and then re-creating observables from the result.

I hope that someone could give me a direction how to solve my issue.

**EDIT**

`takeUntil` requires the conditional observable to emit an item when it actually meets the condition. However, the `getAggregatedNumber()` emits the item on request and completes afterwards. There is no hot observable which always emits the current value if it has changed, so I could apply a filter on it. How could I use `takeUntil` anyway?

Comment: 'takeUntil` should work. (from Wiki - "The difference between this (takeUntil) operator and takeWhile(Predicate) is that here, the condition is evaluated after the item is emitted.") - item emitted and after that condition is checked. Isn't it?

Comment: Use `take(1)` to get one item after that `filter()` for example.

Comment: `takeUntil` is an interesting approach. How to use it as a condition? I understand it that I request the aggregated number in the until-observable and filter the emitted items there?

Comment: As far as I understand your need - `takeUntil` does exactly this "I want to iterator over all of my number generators until the algorithm returns a number matching my condition.". You pass the condition to the `takeUntil` operator. `takeUntil` will pass the items until condition is satisfied (including last item) and then stops.

Comment: I don't get clearly what do you want. You want to force to return just one element to an observable but that element must match with the condition. Am I right?

Comment: Yah! My fault. I haven't seen, that `takeUntil` takes also a `predicate` in RxJava2 instead of an observable. It seems to work, though I should test it more thoroughly. But @Demigod could you please write an answer, so I could accept it?

Comment: @DenisLoh, glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to iterator over all of my number generators until the algorithm returns a number matching my condition.

As far as I understand your need - you need to use `takeUntil(stopPredicate)` operator. Description of this method says

> Returns an Observable that emits items emitted by the source Observable, checks the specified predicate for each item, and then completes when the condition is satisfied.

You pass the condition to the `takeUntil` operator. `takeUntil` will pass the items **until** condition is satisfied (including last item) and then stops.